# Sound settings not saved

Tags: sound, 14.04, microphone, system-settings

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8ObMRANL3A&feature=youtu.be) is a video of what is happening.

Every time I set my input to  "Rear Microphone" it goes back to "Digital input (S/PDIF)" (just by closing the window, not even restarting or logging out). This happens only for the input tab, for the output works fine.
If I run `pactl list sources` here is what I get with the window open:

```
Source #13
State: RUNNING
Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
Driver: module-alsa-card.c
Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Owner Module: 6
Mute: no
Volume: 0:  98% 1:  98%
        0: -0,61 dB 1: -0,61 dB
        balance 0,00
Base Volume:  10%
             -60,00 dB
Monitor of Sink: n/a
Latency: 2693 usec, configured 20000 usec
Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
Properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = "ALC888 Analog"
    alsa.id = "ALC888 Analog"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "0"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel MID"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel MID at 0xfbff8000 irq 46"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "3b56"
    device.product.name = "5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "front:0"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
    device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
    alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC888"
    alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0888,1458a002,00100001"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
Ports:
    analog-input-microphone-front: Front Microphone (priority: 8500, not available)
    analog-input-microphone-rear: Rear Microphone (priority: 8200, available)
    analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, available)
Active Port: analog-input-microphone-rear
Formats:
    pcm
```

And here it is what i get after i close the window:

```
Source #8
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: 0:  40% 1:  40%
            0: -23,88 dB 1: -23,88 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 100%
                 0,00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 36000 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC888 Digital"
        alsa.id = "ALC888 Digital"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "1"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel MID"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel MID at 0xfbff8000 irq 46"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "3b56"
        device.product.name = "5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "iec958:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC888"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0888,1458a002,00100001"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (priority: 0)
    Active Port: iec958-stereo-input
    Formats:
        pcm
```

I was having problems with audio so I ran these commands and I probably messed up something:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio
sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio-utils
sudo apt-get remove pavucontrol
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-utils
```

Here the sound indicator and some of system settings were gone so I had to:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Comment: Changing that setting from `pavucontrol` doesn't work? btw you might want to check the `byzanz-record` package to capture your screen as .gif so you don't have the trouble to upload a video to YouTube. :-)

Comment: Thank you for byzanz, i tried a lot of thing to make a gif but it was too big. I found a way to fix it: reinstalled pavucontrol, rear microphone didn't appear there, changed in sound settings, now it appears also on pavucontrol and it works. Only problem: if i open sound settings again it shows digital input but that's not an issue. Thank you!

Comment: You might consider adding an answer to your own question. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix it: 
reinstalled pavucontrol but rear microphone didn't appear there,
so i changed in sound settings and now it appears also on pavucontrol and it works. 
Only problem: if i open sound settings again it shows digital input but that's not an issue. Thank you!